# How to use icons in Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, icons, xcode5.1

Please can I have a simple explanation on how to add an Icon to an app, then distribute from Xcode. When I try, here are my error messages

> Apple's web service operation was not successful
>
> Unable to authenticate this package: 848430624.itmsp
>
> ERROR ITMS-9000 "Invalid Image Path- No image found at the path
>   referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons':'Icon-Small'" at
>   SoftwareAssests/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)
>
> ERROR ITMS-9000 "Invalid Image Path- No image found at the path
>   referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons':'Icon-Small-40'" at
>   SoftwareAssests/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)
>
> ERROR ITMS-9000 "Invalid Image Path- No image found at the path
>   referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons':'Icon-60'" at
>   SoftwareAssests/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)
>
> ERROR ITMS-9000 "Missing required icon file. The bund;e does not
>   contain an app icon for iPhone/ iPod touch of exactly '120x120'
>   pixels, in .png format for iOS versions > - 7.0" at
>   SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)

Could not start delivery: all transports failed diagnostics

Answer (score 1):

Create an asset catalog with icons. You can easily do it in Xcode:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows that you are using an xcassets file to hold your icons.  If you click the arrow next to the "source" drop down Xcode should open your XCAssets file and then you can simply insert the images of the [appropriate size](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html)

You will also need to add launch images before you can submit your app